# Configuring bibliography with biblatex and apa6 package

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Newbie question here: I am having trouble understanding how apa6 manages citations. I know how to use biblatex and biber:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
```

But when it comes to the apa6 package, you have the option to select biblatex in the declaration:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,biblatex]{apa6}
```

I also have seen the  `biblatex-apa` and `csquotes` packages used in conjunction with the aforementioned ones, which increases my confusion.

So ¿are these packages redundant? ¿which one should I use? ¿what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` is the package used to *style* your bibliography. `apa` is an available style to change the visual apprearance of the bibliography (and the intext cites). You can get the documentation of the style by typing `texdoc biblatex-apa` into a terminal. 
`csquotes` on the other hand is a package to get control over quotations. It was developed by the same author as `biblatex`, hence both can work well together and loading both is recommended.

Now, `apa6` is a class file to change the visual appearance of the whole document to match the APA guidelines. It supports the `biblatex` option and just sets a few options for biblatex, but the user is still responsible for loading `biblatex` with the corresponding option (`style=apa`).

Comment: The [documentation](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf) of the apa6 class says that "biblatex
option directs apa6 to load the biblatex package with the following options:
style=apa6,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt"